# bootstrap-select doesn't work after pjax submission in Yii2

Tags: yii2, pjax, bootstrap-select

I am using yii2 [bootstrap-select](https://github.com/cakebake/yii2-bootstrap-select) in a form which is work with pjax. I have put the

```
cakebake\bootstrap\select\BootstrapSelectAsset::register($this);
```

in views/layout/main.php

It works when the create form is loaded but when the form is submitted bootstrap-select doesn't apply to select elements in the page. the submission and reload the gridview are done using pjax.

Why does it happend?

Comment: try to place `cakebake\bootstrap\select\BootstrapSelectAsset::register($this);` in to your create view file

Comment: I've tried it now, but no difference.

Comment: on which page do you use pjax ? on index page with gridview or on create page ? try to add `cakebake\bootstrap\select\BootstrapSelectAsset::register($this);` in to file with gridview

Comment: in index page and put it on that page too.

Comment: do you use `renderAjax` method in controller to render view ?